# How to loop a MYSQL query / maybe in a function?

Tags: mysql, function, loops, variables, while-loop

What I've got so far is a code which updates one row as based on the IF conditions - but it 
It is important that it is reliable and atomic (so with transaction).

It should loop/repeat itself based on @q which is quantity - however it can be in a MYSQL function rather than one fixed variable. How can I do that? I've added how the table should look like in the end

```
SET @q=1000;
SET @p=5.00;
SET @email='test@test.com';

update 1detail 
SET quantity = 
if((@q := quantity - @q) >= 0, @q, 0)
WHERE price>=@p ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1;
SET @q = if(@q <0,@q-@q-@q, @q);

UPDATE 1detail 
SET quantity =
if(@q > 0, @q,quantity),
email=
if(@q > 0, @email, email)
WHERE price>=@p ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1;
```

The table at the beginning

```
quantity    price   email            datetime
---------------------------------------------------
800          5.00   test1@test.com    oldest   
50           5.00   test2@test.com  2nd oldest
100         10.00   test3@test.com  3rd oldest    (ignore in processing because @p < price)
```

How it should looks like after looping

```
quantity    price   email                                 datetime
-----------------------------------------------------------------
0            5.00    test1@test.com                        oldest           
150*         5.00    test@test.com (changed to @email)     2nd oldest  (now newest)
100         10.00    test3@test.com                        3rd oldest    (ignored)
```

*this has changed as the oldest only had 800 and the 2nd oldest just had 50
So @q= 1000 (@q) - 800 (oldest) = 200
then @q = 200 (@q) - 50 (2nd oldest)

--> @q = 150 
this updates the 2nd oldest row

Comment: It's very unclear, what you're trying to do. Why loop the query? It will update always the same record. It would be best, if you provided sample data and the desired output and explained how the desired output is to be achieved.

Comment: I've edited my question and added the table at the start and wanted output. Hope this helps in some way.

Answer (score 0):

A small loop can be achieved like this :

```
declare @counter int
set @counter=0

gohere:

set @counter=@counter+1
if @counter<10
    BEGIN
        select @counter
        GOTO gohere;
    END
```

Comment: do I have to declare only the variable that changes under the if condition? so in my case @q And would I add the transaction (start transaction and commit after or before BEGIN

Comment: The if condition is just to stop it after 10 runs. The important thing is the gohere:   this can be used to jump back up so for you it should be : set values(first time)   gohere :   "update statements" commit;   Goto gohere*; (goes back up with the newly set values of Q)